# Where can I find the package turtlebot_bringup?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/indigo/TurtleBot%20Bringup#Turtlebot_Bringup) tutorial, directly after set up through [this](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/indigo#installation) tutorial. I am using ROS indigo.

When attempting to run the command

`roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch`

I get an error stating that minimal.launch is not a launch file, and neither is turtlebot_bringup.

roscd cannot find turtlbot_bringup.

I tried installing the package using

`rosinstall ~/ros https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/indigo/turtlebot.rosinstall`

but it didn't appear to do anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195385/where-can-i-find-the-package-turtlebot_bringup?/) by [ros_user_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20524/ros_user_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-10-22**:
have you souce setup.bash in devel directorY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosinstall ~/ros/indigo/turtlebot https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/indigo/turtlebot.rosinstall /opt/ros/indigo`

---

Originally posted by [ros_user_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20524/ros_user_/) with karma: 16 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0